# How to use a vector within a class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I used the Fireworks init function to store a particle into the particles vector class.
And when I try to retrieve the count of the particles vector in the update() function, the particles vector is empty. Why?

Fireworks.cpp class:

```
void Fireworks::init(){
    float x = randf();
    float y = - 1 * randf(); //Going UP
    float z = randf();

    Particle part(position,Vector3f(x,y,z), color, randInt(1,50));
    particles.push_back(part);
}

bool Fireworks::update(){
    Particle particle;
    int count = particles.size(); //Total num of particles in system
    cout << particles.size() << " ";
}

class Fireworks: public ParticleSystem {
private:
  void init();

public:

  Fireworks(Vector3f pos, Vector3f col) {
    position = pos;
    color = col;
    init();
  }

  virtual bool update();
};
```

particlesystem.h

```
class ParticleSystem {
protected:
  vector<Particle> particles;

public:
  //virtual Particle generateParticle();
  virtual bool update(){return false;};
};
```

main.cpp

```
ParticleSystem *PS;
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  PS = &Fireworks(Vector3f(0,0,0), Vector3f(200,0,255));
  glutIdleFunc(move);
}

void move()
{
   PS->update();       
}
```

Comment: This question lacks some code. What is the class declaration ? How are your functions used ?

Comment: It isn't at all clear from the code you posted what you are trying to do. Could you post a minimal code sample that illustrates the problem?

Comment: You are 'unable to retrieve it in in the update function'. But in the code you have posted you are not even trying to retrieve it in the update function. Please explain what you are trying to do and what exactly the problem is, we can't guess.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: (`update` doesn't return anything but is declared as returning `bool`.)

Comment: @jogojapan hi, I added the code of my main.cpp at the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: @Mat Yes, the main particlesystem class's update function does not do anything as it is supposed to be override by the update function of the child Fireworks class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PS = &Fireworks(Vector3f(0,0,0), Vector3f(200,0,255));
```

This introduces undefined behavior. The right hand side creates a temporary, which will be deleted as soon as that full expression is over (i.e. right after the `;`). `PS` will point to a deleted object after that line - doing anything with it is undefined behavior.

Use `new`.

```
PS = new Fireworks(Vector3f(0,0,0), Vector3f(200,0,255));
```

Also, you *must* return from all functions that are declared as returning something (non-void). It doesn't matter if they're virtual or not.

Comment: Be sure to turn on your compiler's warnings, it should have told you there was a problem with that line.

Comment: once again, thank you for taking the time to help me. Greatly appreciated. Have a great weekend!

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you for the reminder. Sorry, newbie here, didn't know there's an accept answer button :p